# How to get aws lambda APIGatewayProxyRequest parameter on dotnet 6 Minimal Api app.MapGet function

Tags: .net, .net-core, aws-lambda

When writing aws lambda on dotnet 3.1, we can get parameters as following;

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
...
}
```

But dotnet 6 minimal api, I can not get this paramter like this;

```
app.MapGet("/students/{name}", async (APIGatewayProxyRequest request)=>
{
..
}
```

Does anybody know how to get this parameter on minimal api?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use Minimal API in .NET Core with AWS Lambda. Follow below steps.

#### 1. Select **AWS Serverless Application** from project templates.

[image]

#### 2. Use **ASP.NET Core Minimal API** blueprint.

[image]

This project uses NuGet package `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer`, that contains a Lambda function (similar to what you have shown in code snippet).

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
...
// 1. this lambda function receives requests from API Gateway
// 2. redirects request to ASP.NET Core controller, process it
// 3. returns the response back to API Gateway
...
}
```

This lambda function is used to translate requests from the API Gateway into the ASP.NET Core framework and then the responses from ASP.NET Core back to API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I cant understand, my project already contains Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer, I dont know  where I use FunctionHandler function and mapget endpoint together in this sample minimal api project

Comment: You can not create api routes using mapget in a Lambda Function project and invoke them directly from API Gateway. API Gateway can only invoke FunctionHandler. You should refer these guides - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/running-serverless-asp-net-core-web-apis-with-amazon-lambda/ & https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your kindness answer. Using this template, there is no FunctionHandler method. I cant find any example for this, functionhandler and controller using with together. Where is position the FunctionHandler method in this pattern. Yes, Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer contains this method. but I'm confused

Comment: LambdaEntryPoint is the entry-point from where request enters your Lambda Function. When you create new Lambda Application from above blueprint, you will get this class. This class inherits from APIGatewayProxyFunction. That contains FunctionHandler. Here is the repo link, you can explore the code and learn from it - https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get aws request objects from HttpContext class.  context.Items[AbstractAspNetCoreFunction.LAMBDA_REQUEST_OBJECT].

Comment: That is what I did also @thunderbolt, but there has to be a better way.